# How to echo random text in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, echo

I have about 300 lines of text that need to be echoed randomly.

Here's my current code:

```
<?php 

$lines = array(
'Line 1',
'Line 2',
'Line 3'
);

$powered = echo $lines[rand(0, count($lines)-1)];

echo $powered;

?>
```

I know that the issue is probably with line 9 because I'm not sure how to assign the echoing to a variable.  I need to be able to include this file in several others and echo `$powered` to get a random line.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: `$powered = $lines[rand(0, count($lines)-1)];`

Comment: @Meredith: `array_rand()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$lines = array("one", "two", "three","four");
for($i =0; i < count($lines)-1;i++){

$line = $lines[rand(0, count($lines)-1)];
$lines = array_diff($lines, array($line));//Use this to remove the index of array
}
```

i wrote this in the stack overflow chat so there might be a problem or two. though, all looks well to me.

Was this what you were looking for?